# Matrix Derivative of this Equation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization

I'm trying to solve this minimization problem:

$$ \min_{\Theta} \frac{C_1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \|\vec{\theta_{j+1}} - \vec{\theta_j}\|^2 ,$$ 
where $\Theta = (\vec{\theta_1}, \vec{\theta_2}, \ldots, \vec{\theta_N})$. (FYI, it's from this [paper](http://papersdb.cs.ualberta.ca/~papersdb/uploaded_files/1060/paper_nips11_survival.pdf)). To find the min, either directly or by Newton's method, I need to differentiate w.r.t $\Theta$. What does the derivative look like? I know it's simple, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be the [shift matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix) and let $P = U^{N-1}$

Then your objective function can be written in terms of $\Theta$ and these 2 matrices as 
$$ \eqalign {
 f = \frac {C_1} {2} (2\Theta:\Theta - 2\Theta:\Theta U - \Theta P:\Theta P - \Theta P^T:\Theta P^T)
}$$
where $A:B$ denotes the [Frobenius product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).

The differential is
$$ \eqalign {
 df &= \frac {C_1} {2} (4\Theta:d\Theta - 2d\Theta:\Theta U - 2\Theta:d\Theta U - 2\Theta P:d\Theta P - 2\Theta P^T:d\Theta P^T) \cr
  &= C_1(2\Theta - \Theta U - \Theta U^T - \Theta PP^T - \Theta P^TP):d\Theta \cr
}$$
The derivative is
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial\Theta} &= C_1\Theta\,(2I-U-U^T-PP^T-P^TP) \cr
}$$
**Update:**

Perhaps this a better motivation for formulating the function in terms of $\Theta$.

The matrix $U$ shifts the columns one position to the right, hence its name.
So $f = \frac {C_1} {2} \|\Theta-\Theta U\|^2$ is almost exactly what we want, except the pesky first column is differenced against a $0$-column.

But we can isolate the first column and subtract it away using the matrix $P$
$$\eqalign{
 \frac {2} {C_1} f &= \|\Theta-\Theta U\|^2 - \|\Theta P\|^2 \cr
   &= (\Theta-\Theta U):(\Theta-\Theta U) - (\Theta P):(\Theta P) \cr
   &= \Theta(I-U):\Theta(I-U) - (\Theta P):(\Theta P) \cr
   &= (I-U)(I-U^T):\Theta^T\Theta - PP^T:\Theta^T\Theta \cr
   &= (I-U-U^T+UU^T-PP^T):\Theta^T\Theta \cr
   &= (I-U-U^T+\bigg[I-P^TP\bigg]-PP^T):\Theta^T\Theta \cr
   &= (2I-U-U^T-P^TP-PP^T):\Theta^T\Theta \cr
} $$
Since $I-PP^T=U^TU$, you can write the function in terms of $U$ alone
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \frac {C_1} {2} \bigg(U^TU + UU^T - U- U^T\bigg):\Theta^T\Theta \cr
}$$